# Facebook PHP SDK 5 posting to page - nobody see posted photos

Tags: facebook

I post photos by Facebook php SDK5 to my page. When I open page I can see all these posted photos. BUT when other people come to my page they don't see these posts.

Here is a code:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'xxx/Facebook/autoload.php';
    $app_id = "xxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxx";
    $page_id = "xxx";
    $token = "xxxx page token";

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'  => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    // описание параметров есть в документации
    $linkData = [
    'message' => 'xxx',    
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('xxx img source'),
    ];

    try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->post("/{$page_id}/photos", $linkData, $token);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    }
```

What's the problem? Why nobody except me don't see these posts? If I post photo by myself in facebook page everybody see it.

Comment: Can you provide a permalink to a post you created on a page that no one can see?